# Select records from one table, check if it exists in another table then insert into a 3rd table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have 3 tables say table A, B, C. Their schema structure is different but they have a unique column ID. Using C# i want to

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

Then check if any of the records selected from A exists in B (ID being key). If it exists i insert the records in C.
How can i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
insert into C(id, Name)
select id, name from A
      inner join B on A.id = B.id
```

Comment: That's not inserting anything into C.

Comment: `@NikhilAgrawal` If this record exists, i want to INSERT in table C if it doesnt exist i want to INSERT the record in table D

Comment: I could not understand what do you mean by `if it doesnt exist i want to enter the record in table D`. If there is no record then nothing will be added in D

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO C(ID, ...)
SELECT A.ID, ....
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```